# Is PUBSUB CHANNELS command blocking Redis server?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

We are known that [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command block Redis server and need to use `*SCAN` commands instead.

As I understand Redis server can handle a lot of pubsub connection. So, if I call [`PUBSUB CHANNELS`](http://redis.io/commands/pubsub#pubsub-channels-pattern) command on such server can it handle pubsub connections or handle other commands during execution of this command?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is single threaded. It can have any number of clients, but the commands that are getting executed is single threaded (one by one).

In PUBSUB you are subscribing to a client, which will hold the connection to the server.

When you publish a message it gets delivered to all the channels that have subscribed, so basically it's a single call which does publishing to all channels in that call itself. So if you have multiple clients (say a million) subscribing to a single channel, it will take some time to publish to all those clients, then yes it is blocking. Also note that blocking will happen only during publish action.

Hope this answers your question.